# Serial editing in general: acceptable or not?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, serial-editing

Other than in special cases, such as previously agreed retagging (burnination requests), is serial editing acceptable in general?

First of all, I have a prejudice against serial editing at all. For a close watcher of couple tags, it disturbs me when many questions get edited in large numbers. It takes time to review them. Also, I have a strong belief that editing should be only *supplementary*, but by no means the main occupation of the participant. If someone has no knowledge to answer, they shouldn't edit anything at all.

I have a feeling that edits should be occasional, not planned. It should happen through normal site use.  "I found this post in the area where I have some experience, and I feel I can contribute a bit", not "Today I'll edit 50 questions just for sake of it!". It looks to me that some users get an editing craze just out of sheer boredom. And the outcome of such campaigns is neutral at best and actively harmful at worst.

Is serial editing frowned upon in general, especially for insignificant changes?

Comment: Good edits are good. Bad edits are bad.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta so, you have seen, say, ten edits in five minutes from the same user, all of which are good? Would it be too much to ask you for a proof?

Comment: The burden of proof is rather on you than me, don't you think?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Surely, then, your question would be not whether serial editing is acceptable or not in general, but rather whether such behavior encourages bad edits?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I've got your point. It's hard to expect anything else on meta.

Comment: There was an interesting example a couple of weeks ago, where somebody was fixing tags on lots of posts that were partly several years old. I forgot the tag name, but there are two very similar looking tags (one the plural of the other) that have completely different definitions. This user was looking for posts that had the wrong one of these two tags, and fixed them. Which seemed perfectly legitimate and possibly useful, but there were a **lot** of them in a short time period.

Comment: Seems related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199792/should-we-do-something-about-enormous-numbers-of-edits-in-short-times and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits

Comment: **"Also, I have a strong belief that editing should be only supplementary, but by no means main occupation of the participant."** Indeed - and I can think of some offenders who do nothing but spam the front page with trivial changes.  But this idea extends in general - site maintenance should only be a minor part of one's role, otherwise there's a very real risk of *losing perspective*.

Comment: Editing is a perfectly legitimate function for any user to be performing, even those <2K users.  One can be looking at a question which is outside of one's expertise, see the question (or answer) has butchered the English language and feel compelled to correct the post.  On the serial re-tagging edit, I am more inclined to agree with you when it comes to tags.  I often reject edits that are _only_ minor retags.  One case where it is permissible is when a new tag is created which might be relevant for existing questions.  In that case, re-tagging multiple questions makes sense.

Comment: _all of you. All of you are terrible and should be ashamed. Edit 15 questions as penance._ [-- Shog9](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285484#2285484).

Answer (score 25):

Is serial editing acceptable in general? In theory, yes. In practice, no.

In theory, it's possible to make a lot of good edits in a short time. You already identified the only problem with that, it bumps a lot of old questions and drives new content off the front page. When there is a tag cleanup, we're always told to be mindful of that.

In practice, I don't see people make a lot of good edits in a short time. What I see in the Suggested Edits review queue are serial *minor* edits. People who remove only "thanks" from a post, but leave all the other problems in place. Or who make dubious re-tags. I've even once seen one of those serial re-taggers slap a tag on a question that had a clear "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" in its tag wiki excerpt!

So in general, I'll say serial editing is bad. An editor should be paying attention to what (s)he is editing, even if it's a simple re-tag. And I've yet to see a serial editor do that.

Comment: I can say that I have done serial edits on questions with "thanks" at the bottom before. I found that those posts usually have other issues too, typically they lack code formatting, in many cases have spelling and other grammatical errors, and sometimes sloppy formatting (huge wall of text). I always fix all errors I see in posts. Edits just removing thanks from posts should be rejected as too minor, or improved to fix other issues.

Comment: @Nate users with over 2k rep can just go ahead and make their incomplete edits without being reviewed.

Comment: @KateGregory Do you see lots of 2k+ rep users making these bad edits? I'd expect most people that hit 2k (and get no reputation from edits anymore) to be making sensible edits, fixing all issues. Since they are no longer rep hunting.

Comment: @Nate They could still be trying to get tag badges, by adding tags to questions to which they have upvoted answers.

Comment: Seems to me that the real problem is that the front page is sorted in such a fashion that editing a question pushes it upwards. Can't see any reason why that should be the case.

Comment: @Carson63000: In a recent discussion about minor edits, it was suggested that there could be an option to mark edits as minor, and those minor edits would not push the question to the top. I really liked that idea.

Comment: @RetoKoradi agreed that sounds like an excellent idea

Comment: The bad thing is not really the serial editing, the bad thing is the robo approving of those...

Comment: @RetoKoradi I don't suppose you have a link for that do you? I don't know how I feel about a checkbox, but I'd love to see tag-only edits not bump.

Comment: @RubberDuck That comment was from a long time ago. I have no specific memory. Your attempts to search for it would probably be as good as mine. I would try something like "minor edit bump" as search terms.

Comment: @S.L. Barth Does editing many posts of a single user cause any reputation changes or something?

Answer (score 17):

I occasionally generate an *ad hoc* review queue for myself. It gives me something to do. For example, I’ve spent some time removing [posts which have titles beginning with “Q:”](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151579/unnecessary-question-labelling), or [posts which use the name of a porn site as an example domain](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com), or other such issues.

Three points:

1. I always read the full thing when I edit, and try to address not only the issue that brought me to the post, but also all others that I see (and I’ll see most of ’em, because I’m a good editor and a compulsive proofreader).
2. I have sufficient rep that my edits go through immediately. This means that (a) I’m not taking up anyone else’s time reviewing my edits, and (b) no one has cause to doubt my motives (I have never edited for rep; I have never done anything for rep).
3. Such reviews of mine are rarely concentrated within a tag, so I won’t be distracting people who are watching any given tag (and the homepage of SO moves far too fast for any one person to influence it noticeably).

Comment: I use a custom-made review queue based on API, rather than Data Explorer. The advantage is that I get real-time data and can focus on recently active questions, thus reducing front-page bumping (this is more relevant on sites other than SO). In case you are interested, see [Review+Edit page](http://stackapps.com/q/4848/26164) on Stack Apps.

Answer (score 5):

Some serial editing is ok, but in general if I have an editing project to do to clean something up, I do it in batches of half-a-dozen or so, so that the front page isn't filled up with my edits.  A little common sense goes a long way.

Having said that, what would really help here if there was a way to  mark an edit as minor so that it doesn't appear on the front page, as per this [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers).

Comment: it can be simply abused.