# How should one ask for clarification on a question if they can't yet comment?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

As a new user (well new by reputation points standards), I sometimes run into limitations posed by the small amount of rep that I have, the most common being the ability to comment. According to Stack Overflow, you should submit a comment if you want to:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Add relevant, but minor or transient information to a post (for example, a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

I completely understand that for low reputation users, we would want to limit criticism (because it may not be constructive), or limit their ability to link questions, but one that befuddles me is the first one; asking for clarification.

As a new, low reputation user, I have been frustrated with this problem before, and it has actually either caused me not to answer a question that I have a working knowledge of, or to wait around for someone else to ask for clarification. The second point of waiting around becomes a much more significant problem for unpopular tags (like one I have a lot of knowledge in, [OBIEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Business_Intelligence_Suite_Enterprise_Edition)).

So to get to the point here, where can a responsible low reputation user ask for clarification if they constantly answer unpopular tags from OPs that don't close their question (mark as answer)? Should I ask in an answer, then edit my answer once I get information back? Or should I wait for others? Some may say to stop answering questions for unpopular tags from low reputation users, but I believe every answer on this site increases its usefulness, and that these unpopular tags could just be a building block for growth if we give good answers.

At the end of the day, I realize this is not a major problem, as 50 reputation is not hard to achieve, but I still think in certain cases it could be a relevant question to ask.

Comment: Rule #1: **Do not ask for clarification in an answer!** Also, if you have at least 20 rep, you can ask a higher-rep user in chat.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - you are smarter than me. I posted your suggestion as answer and it got downvoted. You put is as comment and it got upvoted. Go figure.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 76):

Go and do something else on the site to gain 50 reputation points. This can be any of:

- 5 upvotes on answers
- 5 upvotes on questions
- 3,3 accepts on answers
- 25 edit suggestions accepted
- getting a full bounty of any size, or half a bounty for any full amount greater than or equal to 100

in any combination.

While you can't comment just move on to the next question, if a clarifying comment is really needed then there are enough users with the reputation to add one (or several).

Once you've got 50 rep you can then comment to your heart's content.

The next step is to get 200 points on one site. Then you'll get a 100 point account association bonus on *all* sites so you'll be able to comment everywhere.

Comment: But isn't suggesting many edits contributing to another problem - too many too minor edits?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Do all serial edits have to be minor? [Related discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258424/2846923)

Comment: A problem with "just move on to the next question" is when the new would-be contributor has unique knowledge towards a question that no one else seems to be answering, but needs to ask a clarifying question first.  The stock answer assumes that someone else will deal with it, but for some uniquely worthwhile questions that's not a safe assumption at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I would have thought that is is a very rare edge case. Plus it's really not that hard to get 50 rep

Comment: As with things rare, it may *seem* unimportant to those who habitually hang out here, but it's extremely important to the person asking that question, and the person who could perhaps uniquely answer it.

Comment: A much faster way to accumulate 50 reputation is to have a few decent questions/answers, then post a good question to meta stack overflow about with how if only you had 50 reputation you'd be able to do something useful for the site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, there are problems with everything.  Perfection is the enemy of the good, and most questions do not find the perfect answerer who lacks the 50 reputation to ask the clarifying question which tips the balance between having enough information to answer the question, and not, and so the world falls into shadow.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And if you don't put any barriers to commenting then the site gets overrun with spam, nobody wants to use it, and then almost *nobody* gets answers to their questions.  Trying to ensure that no good user is ever prohibited from doing anything means ensuring that plenty of really bad users are allowed to do all sorts of bad things.

Comment: If you don't give users a rule-compliant way to accomplish important things, some fraction of them will result to rule violation.  And perhaps that's not a bad thing - their point gets made and perhaps promoted to a legitimate comment, and we all get reminded that our site doesn't quite work right.

Comment: You say it's "not that hard to get 50 rep", but as somebody who's been around for a while now, is at over 4000 rep, and has made (I think) a handful of good positive contributions to the site, I have to say that even now, if I had only a few hours to kill, I'd find it hard to find a way to earn 50 rep *without resorting to posting answers to worthless debugging questions*. Much like the worry @SpaceTrucker has about minor edits, I worry about the privilege system forcing people into doing pointless debugging to farm rep.

Comment: @Senhor You need 15 rep to give an upvote, not to receive one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Guess what each of the answers to the clarifying question might be, and provide an answer for _all_ of them.

Comment: That can work when it's an A or B and both are possible to concisely answer.  But more widely exhaustive guess answers tend to end up low quality and rambling.  I've been known to downvote such postings when their content ultimately has little to do with the question which was asked and appear likely to confuse more than help (though chances are I've posted some at some point too).  The site *has* a mechanism for asking for clarification questions, it just doesn't work for everyone.

Comment: This doesn't help a user ask a clarifying question _in a timely fashion_

Answer (score 43):

While ChrisF provides the answer as things are right now, I've been [doing some thinking about how we could enable commenting for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/226183#226183).

The minimum reputation limit for commenting on Stack Overflow is intended to prevent spam and noise. Stack Overflow is constantly attacked by spammers and trolls, so some safeguards are needed. We don't have a similar reputation requirement for questions and answers, because we have moderation tools that help us identify and remove spam and undesirable content coming in via those post types.

The minimum reputation requirement for people to leave comments is a constant source of frustration for new or less active users. People find something factually wrong or in need of correction in an answer, and they don't want to go and have to spam answers to get enough reputation just to comment. Many turn to leaving answers (since they don't have a reputation requirement), which then clutters up the site and wastes our time in cleanup.

Maybe it's time to think about relaxing this, contingent on proper tools being made available to moderate comments. First, we have to require users to sign up for a full account in order to comment (as we do for questions).

As I describe in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/226183#226183), one of our first lines of defense against spam is the review system, particularly the Late Answers and First Posts queues. Late Comments and Comments by New Users queues would allow the community to catch spam or noise comments and vote to delete them right from there (and flag them as spam for moderators to burn the accounts). This would have caught several spammers we've had who got above the 50-point threshold via sock puppets and poor reviewers, who them proceeded to spam for months before being caught.

Beyond that, better means of searching comments would allow us to pick out common noise comments or spammed URLs. There might be other tools that could be added to this, but these alone would provide us with good means of reviewing and dealing with incoming comments from 1-rep users.

With these and maybe a couple other safeguards, I can see us thinking about opening up commenting without a rep requirement. This would both reduce user frustration and clutter from non-answers that come in every day.

Comment: I was never a fan of the 50 point threshold.  My two cents would be to allow <50-rep users to comment, but if any >1,000-rep user flag their comments, then the 50 point threshold gets put in-place instantly.  Just a brainstorm.

Comment: @LarsTech Some flags do not indicate abuse. Say a comment requesting clarification was already addressed by the asker. An "obsolete" flag is then appropriate, but can't be treated negatively - the commenter did nothing wrong. I'd say that accumulation of three "too chatty" flags on *existing* (as opposed to removed) comments should trigger threshold increase, and "obsolete" flags should have no effect on threshold increase.

Comment: @KubaOber Sure, limit it to just the `rude or offensive` flag.  Maybe the `not constructive`, too.  Depends what most users flag spam comments as.

Comment: +1. 50 rep may seem easy to obtain for regular users, but for new users it can be a giant hurdle. Questions are expected to meet a high level of quality, and many good questions have already been asked so the new users' questions would be marked as dupes. Answering can also be a challenge for new users, who have less experience in providing good answers here, especially when high-rep users make a habit of giving short answers ASAP then editing them in the 5-min window.

Comment: What about reviewing first comments of users which do not have yet 50 rep in a another review queue? That way we could filter spam out and would afterwards kind of trust the commenter to be a real human. On the pro side we would avoid a lot of misused answers and gain some more feedback.

Comment: @LarsTech I referenced you and Brad in this post in regards to the comment threshold, I wonder if you would take a look at it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311700/how-might-we-solve-the-50-reputation-comment-limit?noredirect=1#comment1018858_311700)

Answer (score 7):

While it's frustrating not being able to comment and thus help out, that doesn't mean using the "answer" field for a comment is therefore ok.
You're bypassing site systems, which are there for very good reasons.

The answer should be an actual answer to the question, not comment or discussion trying to ascertain what the answer will be.
That is for comments (yes, ironically).

It's frustrating, but look at it this way:

If, as a new user, you came here to ask for help with something, then asking *good* questions will give you rep.

If however you only came to help out, firstly that's great, however as you are here to help, you say, then *help* in other ways first, so you gain some rep.
Then you can help in questions which need comments before an answer is possible.

Or, of course, help out by answering questions which need no comments or anything clarifying first!

It's not quite as easy as some make out. It'll take a few hours of raking around, but that is the entire point of you needing to earn rep, and thus privileges, before you can do certain things.

You're working around the site earning a bit of rep means you learn the site, protocols,  etc.
I doubt you're here to just answer a few questions and then leave forever, so don't be in a rush to desperately get 50 rep so you can comment and join in. It'll come, and more naturally means you'll know what you're talking about when you do get to comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you need additional information to answer the question, the question **as it stands** is off topic (Unclear What You Are Asking,  Too Broad or Primarily Opinion Based). As a new low reputation user, you have probably not yet learned which kinds of questions are unsalvageable, and what kinds of clarifications are needed. So your keenness to answer the question way be misplaced. Use the site a bit longer and answer questions you can answer without clarification.

Answer (score -2):

I know it is not a perfect answer (and I was subject of this limit too; asked a question in answer, and **lost** my precious reputation :-( ) but here is a workaround:

You only need 20 reputation to participate in chat - where you may ask your comments to be added by someone who can.

And I know that getting even 20 reputation is becoming harder as most questions being asked are low-quality noise and you really need to wade through a raw stream of stinking noise to get some answerable niche question (which will gain you only a few points, because it is niche and newbie who asked it does not know to upvote and accept it).

All such tricks could be collected in some FAQ page, helping people who want to invest time to learn how to work with the community. So when you cannot comment, link might show how to gain more reputation, with tricks like this one.

Comment: "All such tricks" are wrong. If you want to participate in this site, you should do so without needing "tricks". If you want to comment, earn enough reputation to do so properly. You don't have to post answers to do so. If you don't want to do the work to earn the reputation for privileges, that's OK, but don't try to find ways around not having them. If you don't want to abide by the guidelines here, go somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite I think he has a point though. Participating means mostly answering questions or posing them. For someone not very proficient but just wanting to discuss a topic, participation is a bit difficult at first. I know, it's only a very small hurdle but it's also directly at the beginning. One could imagine a lower limit for commenting, say for example 30 rep.

Comment: @KenWhite - OK so if someone has reputation 25, cannot comment and need to ask question (to be able to answer question better and get reputation, instead of posting answer with wrong assumption which will be downvoted), best place is to go somewhere else. Now I get it. Sorry I missed it. Such attitude is exactly the reason why I choose to participate in SO communities less.

Comment: *best place is to go somewhere else* - That's **not** what I said at all. I said that if you **don't want to follow the guidelines like everyone else, you should feel free go go somewhere else instead**. The guidelines exist for a reason. @Trilarion: The exact reason the rep requirement is where it is at is because users with little or no rep posted lots and lots of noise, comment, insults, and chat before participating here enough to know how the site works and what is (and isn't) appropriate.

Comment: comment on the original question ("Rule #1") says exactly what I said, and it got upvotes. So not everyone is as unwelcoming to beginners like you are. BTW noise in chat is substantially less disruptive. But OK, i just disagree with your opinion, but you have right to do whatever you want, and I do too. I just tried to explain you (and others) how unwelcoming forum this could be for beginners. Especially now, when it is so much harder to gain reputations for newcomers.

Comment: @KenWhite I doubt the rep requirements needs to be exactly where it is now. This is not exactly rocket science and behavior patterns change constantly as well as tracking technology. See also [Brad Larsons answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258670/1536976).

Comment: @PeterMasiar I guess SO assumes that either your programming skills are either so high that you can easily answer tons of questions or so low that you must have tons of questions to be answered, so gaining rep is basically inevitable as long as you aren't a troll. I guess this is not completely right and I see sense in some comments from people without rep but I'm also concerned of separate these comments correctly from the noise. So you lose always something and that's why you will find all sorts of opinions about it.

Comment: @Trilarion: I doubt that the number was just arbitrarily plucked out of thin air for no reason. You're right - it's not rocket science. It's common sense that we don't want users who have zero experience with how the site operates posting comments willy-nilly. It takes minimal effort to earn 50 points, and spending the time to do so increases the time the person spends on the site and familiarizes themselves with how things work.

Answer (score -11):

As someone who is currently facing this problem, here are my two cents.

The fundamental issue here is "how to make sure that a new user is not a spammer". One idea I have is to get the new user vouched by others. If a user is vouched by X other users, he gets to comment. The exact value of X can be determined by the moderators (10 or 20 should be good enough IMHO).

This way, if you know other geeks who hang around Stack Overflow, you can ask them to vouch for you.

You can go fancy and have all sorts of restrictions to make sure that the person vouching for others is human and not a spammer himself (ex:- to be able to vouch, you need to have reputation > some threshold) etc., but the idea remains same.

Comment: Thus you invite a new kind of [voting ring](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322114/2564301): *trusted* rings! (Note votes on Meta do not count for your reputation, for better or for worse.)

Comment: Honestly, this is _kinda_ already what the reputation system and votes are for- If someone thinks your post is good and correct, they can vote it up, telling the system to trust you a few points more. Likewise, if your post is of bad quality, wrong, or lacks in research, users can vote your posts down, telling the system to trust you a little bit less. Reputation, more than anything, is a measure of how much the system trusts you. As a warning, asking friends you know to vote for you just because they know you is _voting fraud_ and can/will get you a suspension. I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: @usr2564301 Just to be clear, voting on ***child*** Metas does not affect reputation. It does on the main Meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/).