# Comment alternatives for low rep users

Tags: support, reputation, comments

I found a post that seems to be relevent to a problem that I am also trying to solve. However, I can't get the example code in the answer to run, and I'd like to comment to ask the poster for some clarification. As you can see, I'm don't yet have enough rep to comment. What alternatives do I have? Should I ask a new question even though I think the existing answer is what I'm looking for?

Edit: This is related to [How should one ask for clarification on a question if they can't yet comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment?rq=1) But is focused on asking for clarification on answers, not questions.

Comment: Can you try that existing answer? If it works for you, problem solved. If it doesn't, then you can ask your own question referencing the one you found and stating why the answer there did not work for you (to avoid it being closed as a duplicate).

Comment: In this case, the existing answer contains code that doesn't compile on my machine. I'm not sure if that's enough of a reason for a whole new question. I was hoping to simply clarify the code a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the description of the duplicate close reason

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

An answer that doesn't work doesn't count in this regard.

If you can't find a question that already has an answer to your question, then it's fine to post a new question.

---

That being said, try to make the existing answer work.  It's not surprising that it doesn't just compile out of the box.  If you're planning on just copying the code from an answer without actually understanding the answer, then your question might not be well received, and any new answers won't be that useful for you anyway.

If it doesn't compile, than the compiler should tell you why not.  Try to figure out why it's not working, and if you can't **then you can ask a question about *that***.