# Comment asking for clarifications vs flagging question as unclear

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, reputation, privileges

At the moment I have 17 points of reputation. That means that I can flag a question as unclear, but I can't comment it to ask the OP to improve it to make it more clear. Why does it happen?
Moreover, I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment) question's answers, and someone says that I can write in chat asking someone else to comment it for me.
So, to make it short, why can't I help while I can still make something less constructive as asking for the question to be closed?

**EDIT**: I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing) question, but it's definitely not the same topic beacuse I am talking about people who cannot comment, that OP is talking about people who can do both the actions (comment AND flag). They talk about time, I talk about opportunity of anticipating a privilege.

Comment: Flagging for close, as it works toward preventing bad answers from clogging up the site, is arguably *more* constructive than commenting, and it's certainly a lot more controlled and less likely to cause trouble.

Comment: The suggestion to ask in chat comes from [an answer with a score of –6](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258709/366904). Probably not what the community at large recommends that you do.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, I thought that commenting can help the OP in improving the quality of the question, I suppose they can't see the flag so they can't know how I find the question unclear.

Comment: @Cody Gray, it also comes from a +5 comment.

Comment: @SamCle88: That's true, but a random comment needn't carry much weight. Closing, however, pretty much guarantees that they either listen and fix, or the question no longer harms anything.

Comment: @SamCle88: Comments can't be downvoted, by the way, which is why answers are a much more reliable way to tell what is and isn't a good idea.

Comment: @SamCle88 It's *possible* for the author to learn how they can improve their question from a comment.  It tends to not actually work out all that well in most cases though.  The advice has to be clear as to what needs improvement, the author needs to care enough to want to improve their question, they need to not act defensively, they need to be *able* to make the noted improvements, etc.  Yes, it can happen, but in the majority of cases it ends up with the author not bothering, or an argument starting that goes nowhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

Comment: @gnat, it's definitely not the same topic, sir. I am talking about people who cannot comment, that OP is talking about people who can do both the actions (comment AND flag). They talk about time, I talk about opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, to make it short, why can't I help...

Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you. At under 50 rep, the system doesn't trust you enough to make comments that aren't spammy or garbage.

This is nothing against you personally. There are lots of people who wish to post spam, malicious content, or offensive garbage. Most of it gets taken care of quickly because most users are able to flag, edit, close, or otherwise moderate content.

But comments can't be edited by the community and only enough of the spam flags will auto-delete a comment. Otherwise a diamond moderator has to deal with them. Therefore, it requires more rep to leave a comment than it does to post a question or answer.