# What is the best way to ask "how did you?" questions on an old question?

Tags: discussion

I have found old questions (two years to seven years for the sake of argument) and answers that are close to what I need to know, and in some of the questions there is useful work already done that I want to ask the OP how did you even get that far? What is your OS? What preliminary tools did you use? But these are old questions and I haven't found the proper guidance yet to know if commenting on an aged question is rude or bad practice. I have not found a way to reach out directly to another user either. Is there such a method? Is it restricted for 'low points" users?

Comment: You may want to review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment

Comment: Do you mean ask the author for clarifications on their question so that you can answer it better?

Comment: @Dharman -- No - I mean for my related question (not close enough to use the answers from this one) if I could just learn some of the underlying techniques the OP used in getting to THEIR question, I would be able to make a lot of progress on my own. Makes sense? May I quote a specific example?

Comment: It seems you need to ask your own question about where you are stuck.  You can cite the other question as a reference, but make sure you indicate how your question is different from that one and what you are asking that is not covered in the answers to the other question.  If you can comment, you can drop a comment to your own question that is targeted at the OP from the original question to see if they can help you with yours, but that's the extent of person to person communication on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I reviewed that post and answers and did not find it adequate to answer these questions. Mostly it was back and forth arguing about what should be point thresholds, not relevant, except in the sense that I am where I am and that isn't going to change except in a negative way if I ask a poorly formatted question.

Comment: From your profile, it looks like you mostly ask about Python. If you want to discuss stuff related to Python, you're welcome to visit the [SO Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). You can read our rules [here](https://sopython.com/chatroom). We can help with questions that may be too broad for the main SO site, and general brainstorming, but we still need you to explain your question clearly & coherently.

Comment: There's no point in asking other OPs anything if they are not logging in. If their profiles show something like _"Last seen more than 2 years ago"_ they won't even see your comment. But even if they do, they may ignore it, or not remember anything about the issue now. Expect nothing, and be pleasantly surprised if you get a helpful response. A better approach would be to cite those other questions in your post, explaining why they are not helpful to you. That helps in two ways: it clarifies your problem, and precludes the possibility of your post being closed as a duplicate of those.

Comment: Thanks all, please consider this done

Comment: For a question that's years old, even if the person being commented to is active there's a good chance it won't help.  If I'm asked about something I did years ago at a previous employer in a stack I no longer work with I'm very unlikely to remember any details about it; and can no longer fire up a copy of the code to take a look.

Answer (score 28):

The best way for you would be to ask a new question. If the topic you are searching for doesn't have adequate answers on Stack Overflow yet, then your responsibilty is to post this question so that an answer may be found.

There's no way to contact the author of that question. Stack Overflow is not a forum and you can't reach out to other people to have a discussion on how they did a project.

Comment: grok. I will try to follow this guideline and @jfriend00 's advice and format a very specific question that may elucidate a useful and focused answer.

Answer (score 18):

> [H]ow did you even get that far? What is your OS? What preliminary tools did you use?

In general, I agree with Dharman that new questions should be asked as a "new question". However, your examples sound more like you would like *a clarification about details on an existing answer*.

In that case, it's perfectly fine to leave a comment. The age of the question is completely irrelevant. Some users leave the site for good 10 seconds after having received an answer to their question, others stay around for more than a decade. And even if the original author is not active anymore, it's quite possible that *someone else* sees your comment and knows the information you are looking for.

Comment: I would say that if the original author doesn't see your comment, it's *extremely unlikely* that someone random will have anything useful to add.  Old questions don't get nearly the same amount of traffic as new questions.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Unlikely, indeed, but it has happened (at least to me, iirc).

Comment: @MarkRansom: Maybe not quickly, like maybe years later.  I sometimes respond to old un-answered comments if they're asking things I can imagine other future readers might be wondering, especially if it makes a useful addition to the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did say unlikely, not impossible. I'm sure I've done the same myself.  But since the question was about which approach would be more fruitful, I thought it was a point that needed to be made.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Fully agreed if we're talking about practical results in the *short* term, where asking a new question is the other option.

Comment: Now that I can comment this will all go a little easier, ha.

Answer (score 7):

There's something that worries me from your question:

> I haven't found the proper guidance yet to know if commenting on an aged question is rude or bad practice

Commenting asking for clarification is never rude or bad practice. Commenting alone even if it's not asking for clarification is never rude. That's literally the reason why "comments" exist:

[image]

The worst that can happen is that the author never sees your comment, the best is that it respond to your query, so there's nothing to lose and too much potential to win. Don't try to guess if it ever going to respond. Heck, I've been replied to months after my comment.

Comment: But some construe rudeness if comments (and posts) *deviate from the* ***letter*** *form*, including explicit addressing (e.g., *"Good afternoon, Braiam. It is a very nice day outside. The sun is shining. <the content>. Regards, Peter Mortensen"*.) (Though, ironically, it is also rude to assume being in the same time zone (*"Good afternoon"*) or the same geographical location (*"It is a very nice day outside"*).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen personally, I tend to edit out those from my reading and get to the meat of the comment. BTW, that someone considers a behavior rude doesn't make it universally rude. Otherwise, there would be no way to not offend someone.

Comment: You might want to clarify this meta answer that it's only ok to ask for clarification of something the answer was already trying to explain.  It's *not* ok to basically ask a followup question or how to apply the answer to a very similar related case.  That's something a lot of beginners misunderstand, even going so far as to post a new question as an *answer* instead of comment.  So just for the sake of any future readers of this answer, might want to be specific.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's up to the author to determine. If there's something that isn't explained and could be edited in the answer, that would be best. I prefer giving them all the go to doing comments and that if the author believe that the commenter would be best served to ask an entire new question they can tell them so. In other words, I don't want readers to restrict their comments. I prefer them to comment first and then ask new questions later.

Comment: So far whenever I have posted a question or answer (I have deleted several) someone has edited out any form of polite expression, so my interpretation is that I should behave like a Vulcan that wants information or one who has a useful contribution to make.

Comment: @JackFisher no Vulcan, just don't waste the reader time. Get to the meat immediately. Ask what you want to ask, nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Precisely.  A question is a question, not an email.  For 100% of the people reading your question in (say) 1 years time (and 99.5% now), the "politeness" is just a distraction.  Imagine if you were reading an FAQ and ever question in the FAQ started with *"Dear support, I hope this finds your well, <blah blah>"*.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [sufficient reputation (75 points)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), another approach would be to post a "bounty" asking for answers that explain in more detail how to solve the problem.

But asking a new question is probably a better idea, as per [Dharman's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417894/139985).

Comment: So, are you saying OP shall first wait 11 years (based on his average rep gain during the past 7 years) until he has enough reputation, then spend all the points for a bounty so afterwards he isn't even able to comment any more? Sorry, but the bounty approach is not working for a lot of people.

Comment: His past rep gain will be related to the amount of help he provides to other people.  But yea ... for this person and other people who don't ask questions and write answers, this is not going to help.

Comment: I was off the site for a long time. Now I believe I am back for a while. My work is going to require growth mindset in programming for the foreseeable future.