# What should I do about a "not an answer" post posted by someone who has less than 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, not-an-answer

I often see that users of less than 50 reputation post something on a question such as, "This is not an answer, but I have had this issue too." I know that [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment) details more of what should be done if a user cannot yet comment, but what should I do about the "not an answer" post by the user? They recognize that it is not an answer and state that clearly. Should I just flag this as **Not An Answer**, or try to tell the user not to post something like that because it should be a comment?

In simpler words, is one of those posts simply cause for a **Not An Answer** flag, or is there some other way that I approach it, seeing as the user could not have posted a comment yet?

Comment: It's not an answer, right? So flag as such. If you want to post any extra guidance, you could but it's not necessary.

Comment: No need to comment in addition to flagging. They should get the message well enough when their post is deleted.

Comment: This is not a comment but to answer your question: just flag it and move on.

Comment: For what it's worth, that really shouldn't be a comment either if it doesn't contribute anything to the discussion. So even if they had enough reputation it would still be flag-worthy.

Comment: "If you want to post any extra guidance, you could but it's not necessary.", "They should get the message well enough when their post is deleted."

No wonder why SO is considered so toxic by so many people.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*

Comment: @Alex I should have been more clear about it, but I meant that they will literally get a message explaining why their post is being deleted when people vote to delete it in the LQP queue. I'm personally not in favor of people commenting in addition to that because as well as being redundant, those types of comments are often less polite than the automatic message from the review queue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flag it as Not An Answer because it isn't an answer. The fact that they admit that it isn't an answer doesn't make it ok; if anything, it makes it even worse because they know that it's wrong.

The fact that they can't comment, vote, or set bounties yet is not an excuse for them to misuse the answer section.

Comment: You can also downvote such "answer" as it is extremely unlikely to be *useful*.