# Where should we direct new users who post comments as answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, new-users, not-an-answer

I have been seeing this happen for as long as I've been using SE sites - people posting for the first time on whatever sub-site as an answer, when it is a comment or question.

What is the best **page** on the SE network to refer them to, in order to give them a quick intro / explanation of how to use the site? (I assume there is a page that serves this purpose, but a quick web search did not turn up what I had in mind.)

I recall that there is a page that covers this that appears when first joining an SE site, but some people apparently don't make any effort to read/understand that before posting.

I'm just tired of having to type out an explanation each time, and want to copy/paste. Thanks.

Comment: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) would be a good start.

Comment: MSE canonical: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). MSO question: [How should one ask for clarification on a question if they can't yet comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment)

Comment: If you flag the answer as "Not an Answer", which *should* push the answer to the review queue, there is a canned comment in there that users can use that tells the OP why comments as answers are incorrect use of answers.

Comment: Canned comments are somewhat controversial (more specifically, how they are used, e.g. in an overgeneralised manner, not tailored to the specific situation), though the term itself has [now been canonicalised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420897/staging-ground-workflow-canned-comments).

Comment: Even [Jon Skeet uses canned comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495587/i-need-an-algorithmic-help-to-convert-an-input-array-object-to-arraylistlistin#comment114042634_64495587).

Comment: I also very often see the case where people post a comment as an answer because they don't have sufficient privileges to post a comment. I think this is the problem for a huge amount of comments posted as answers. IMHO, this privilege barrier makes no sense since new users are allowed to answer a question but not to ask for clarification before answering... (which is not fair and pointless if I may say)

Comment: (That being said, I'm **not** telling that it's fine to post comments as answers)

Comment: @Fareanor most of those comments boil down to "Did you find a solution?" or "Can you answer my question *insert code + question*". Neither of those should be posted as either comments nor answers. The former even shouldn't be posted as questions.

Comment: @Adriaan It seems you overlooked my comment :) I was talking about real and valid comments posted as answers (people often add an apology at the end of their "comment" for having posted it as an answer since they could not write it in the comment section). And I've seen it a lot of times, you've no idea.

Comment: @Turamarth no, it would not, why do you think so?

Comment: @CodeCaster My comment referred to the question asked inside the post: _What is the best page on the SE network to refer them to, in order to give them a quick intro / explanation of how to use the site?_. Considering that Mentalist doesn't have the Informed badge I thought it would be a useful link.

Comment: @Tura sure, that page mentions _"Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer."_, but it also contains a boatload of other text. It's not clear from _just_ pointing to that page that one should not use answers to ask for clarification, but comment instead, nor does it mention to "if you want to comment but can't, wait until you can". It's a generic page, not a specific one. But you're right, the tour _does_ answer that question from the OP.

Comment: @Fareanor the 50 rep limit is in place for very good reasons. Read the links in Abdul Aziz Barkat's comment up at the top of this thread for explanations. The way you solve not having enough reputation to post a comment is to earn enough reputation to post a comment. It's not really that hard. Additionally, users can always post comments on their own posts, regardless of rep. We *need* a barrier to entry here.

Answer (score 28):

You don't need to type out a reason. Just flag the answer as "Not an Answer", and (if you feel inclined to) downvote it. This should push the answer to the review queue which will handle the answer.

Within the queue for such answers, there are canned comments that can be posted on as answers. If it's the original poster, then the following canned comment is used:

> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review]

And if it's someone other than the OP:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review

The "From Review" text is also a link to the review itself.

Comment: Note that this comment is _not_ posted if a moderator beats the review queue to it and just hits the delete button, though (we don't have an easy way to also post the comment from the mod tools, other than going through the normal commenting flow).

Answer (score 5):

I usually write the following and then flag that as "not an answer":

> This is not an answer. Soon with enough SO reputation you'll be able to add comments. Until then, avoid posting comments&questions as answers.

Additionally, a link to [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/) can be provided.

Comment: This is ten times better than the "This does not provide an answer [...] From review" canned comment, which isn't actionable and doesn't tell the user to not do so in the future.