# Is this user being too noisy?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This user has a page or more of approved edits - that carry on in the proposed edit review queue-, as you may see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748777/c-o?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1), which involve fixing always the same "noisy" issue: thanks found in the questions.

It seems very suspicious to me: what's going on?

What I wonder is **how** are they finding such questions, given the short time lapse between most of the edits? Bots scanning through questions for that pattern? Multiple fake accounts?

Of course I may be wrong and have overstated that behavior -- just wanted to have somebody with definitely more tools and capabilities than me to have a second check and act accordingly.

Comment: It definitely looks like that is all the user is fixing when many posts could use some more fixing up. Shame on him and the reviewers

Comment: What's likely happening is that the user is searching through the site for a specific sentence, and then removing that (and, as far as I can see, only that). I left a comment asking him to stop. Don't know what the policy on mod action is in these cases

Comment: @codeMagic In fact I noticed a bunch of questions one after the other from the same user and making always the same "fix". What's more suspicious may be the source, that is _how_ they're finding it (maybe a bot or multi-account).

Comment: I've suspended them from suggesting edits for a day to slow this down a bit while this is being discussed. I can lift that ban if people think this is acceptable.

Comment: Suddenly my "They're up to 45 edits" or whatever I used in my mod election question doesn't sound as made up as I thought it did...

Comment: @Brad: How about suspending some of the reviewers that are letting these through?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really fair to blame the reviewers. One or two of these isn't really a problem, just a mediocre edit. It certainly doesn't stand out to me as exceptionally bad until you notice the 50 other edits.

Comment: @resueman:  I think the reviewers should be taken to task for those reviews, [especially ones similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10404649) since they managed to miss the *first* "Thank you in..." block!

Comment: If this user is searching for posts containing "thanks in advance" but then editing all issues they find, he or she should carry on! However, it depends on whether they are aware of the various unwritten memes of the site - they are a lot of guidelines (e.g. about title tagging) that take a while to absorb, and so if they don't yet have immediate edit rights, they may be best advised to slow down... especially if the edit queue is being flooded with trivial changes.

Comment: "How are they finding such questions" - the search facility, I would expect. I don't think there's any evidence of multiple accounts, unless I've missed something. FWIW I'd venture so far to say that a search of "thanks in advance" would be very likely to find posts that need editing, so this editor is _nearly_ doing the right thing.

Comment: @resueman It's absolutely correct to blame the reviewers.  That's not an edit that should be approved even if there's only one of it.  That there are dozens of them just makes it that much worse.

Comment: @Servy On some of them, absolutely. But there's [some](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10404803) where nothing else jumps out as obviously in need of fixing. Taken in isolation, one of those edits being approved seems understandable. I'm not saying the edits are great (or even worthwhile), just that a reviewer who decides to let a small improvement through isn't completely unjustified.

Comment: @resueman The edit is not a meaningful improvement in the quality of the post.  It's the kind of thing that you should change if you're actually in there making other meaningful edits, but it's not worthwhile to do in isolation.

Comment: Source? Google this: site:stackoverflow.com/questions "i want a coke"

Comment: It was a test I conducted after noticing exactly this edit on a question of mine. I pondered what's the incentive? and it became obvious. All of the stuff was peer-reviewed so I don't get it, if this kind of clean up is not welcomed why do they get accepted?

Comment: @C.O. [serial minor edits are usually frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258459/4320665).  You need to fix as much as you can for each post.  And while it is an improvement, leaving the rest of the problems makes it not enough of one.

Comment: @C.O. As for why they get accepted, it depends. Some reviewers accept any tiny improvement that comes through, some may have only seen one or two of your edits and not realized you were on an edit spree, and some... Some don't even pay attention and just accept every single edit, good or bad, that crosses their paths. We call that last group robo-reviewers, and they more often than not teach editors that their bad edits aren't that bad.

Comment: @C.O.: the need for peer reviewing is *precisely* why this is frowned upon. You are wasting time and votes in that already filled-to-the-brim queue. Should you ever pass >2000 rep points, you will find that some of these objections go away.

Answer (score 15):

This is definitely abuse of the editing system, and fishing for cheap reputation points.

The user is clearly searching for a specific term to edit, and ignoring other issues in the posts they're "fixing".

Comment: I wouldn't mind someone doing a mass cleanup of "thanks" in posts....but only once they have the ability to edit a question. They should not pick single little things like that out for suggested edits, as it creates too much work for others with too little benefit.

Comment: @mason yeah, mass cleanups are ok-ish - if you really, really fix everything in the posts you come across.

Comment: Why fix *everything* in one shot if what you're trying to do is focus on a specific cleanup task (assuming you have the ability to edit posts and not just suggest edits)? If you only have the ability to suggest edits, then yes, fix everything you can find so we don't have a lot of noisy suggested edits.

Comment: @mason because the suggested edit review queue isn't the only area negatively impacted by mass edits.

Comment: @mason an edited post always pops up to the top, whether you have less than 2000 rep or more. That one should fix everything that's wrong with a post is a general rule around here and it's a good one. Otherwise we'd have loads of folks doing the low-hanging fruit, doing disingenious searches for "bad" content etc., and almost no one doing the hard stuff that actually requires you to *think*.

Comment: I disagree that it's a good rule. If bumping things to the top is the reason we don't want those types of mass edits for single problems, then perhaps we should revisit allowing a post to get bumped to the top?

Comment: @mason bumping posts puts hundreds or thousands of eyeballs on the edit. That helps stop bad users from doing bad things. Not even the highest ranking users are trusted to do edits without public scrutiny

Comment: and it brings a clarified question back to the top of the list, where it can be re-evaluated.

Comment: *"an edited post always pops up to the top"* - only if you are sorting questions by "active" or looking at the home page.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then create a separate page where you see a list of edited posts. That way anyone can check them if they want to. My overall point is that I think it's a bad idea to discourage people from doing a mass cleanup of a single problem like that. And that anything that prevents people from doing that should be re-evaluated to see if we can do things differently.

Comment: Nothing wrong with perusing bad content on a global scale - if done with restraint. I have my pet peeves but try not to flood the main page too much. Now, flooding the *review queue* with trivial edits, that's a whole 'nother pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @mason `Then create a separate page where you see a list of edited posts. That way anyone can check them if they want to` but it's unlikely that anybody *would* want to look at that page; you'd lose the eyeballs that are so important to quality control. `My overall point is that I think it's a bad idea to discourage people from doing a mass cleanup of a single problem like that.`  I don't think so at all. In  grey areas, for example, mass cleanups allow individuals to impose their own interpretation of the rules on everyone else.

Comment: The community can edit content just fine, and through many edits by different users (and discussions about them) come up with rules and standards. If we should be making it easier for users to fix problems in posts, it's with the really *hard* problems that actually require thinking and engagement, not brain-dead search+replace stuff.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The consensus is pretty clear that "hi" and "thanks" and signatures in posts aren't what we want. When I think about if an edit is good or bad I only have one question - does it make the post better, or does it make it worse? I don't care if it was easy or hard as long as the post ends up better.

Comment: @mason but that doesn't take into account the cost of the edit in terms of the people who have to look at it as part of the quality control process. And that cost is always going to be there, you can't make it go away by abandoning edit notifications on a page that no one looks at.

Comment: @mason Is it really clear? The help center links to this on asking good questions: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#courtesy, which sort of encourages those `"thanks for your time"` kind of comments. It's not 100% clear to me whether those "Hi" and "Thanks" kind of things are truly against the site's interests just based on the help center. If I'm overlooking something and it's clearly against them, then what this user is doing shouldn't be considered a trivial edit so much as a "good edit" (even if doing it en masse is abuse). If "hi" and "thanks" is okay, then "trivial".

Comment: @Pekka웃 If you've got a certain level of reputation, I fully trust you to be able to handle edits without wanting to check everything you've done. I can still manually check if an issue arises, but I don't see the need to check *everything*.

Comment: @Ike I have never seen anywhere that we've encouraged people to pollute questions or answers with "thanks" or "thanks in advance" or anything like that Questions and answers are supposed to be reference material, like an encyclopedia. When's the last time an encyclopedia article ended with "I hope this helps"? Never. If you want to do it in a comment, then I'm fine with that. But let's not pollute the actual posts.

Comment: @mason it's very kind of you that you would trust me to do unsupervised edits - but remember that for your idea to work, you'd have to trust every user on SO with more than 2000 reputation points. That is asking... a lot. (Not to mention that bumping a post has other side effects pretty essential to the system, too, mentioned above)

Comment: @mason I agree wholeheartedly, just kind of pointing out that it might not be so clearly a violation of the rules for asking questions based on the help center (perhaps it should be). If it were, then I no longer think we can label what this user is doing as "trivial edits", but rather a good enforcement of the rules (albeit doing it en masse is probably some sort of abuse to collect badges or something).

Comment: @Pekka웃 So let's tweak the system a bit. At X level we only trust you to suggest edits. At X2 level we trust you to make edits, but we want high visibility into those edits (perhaps we sample 50% of your edits to make sure they're good) and we discourage mass edits. At X3 level we fully trust you to edit posts and make mass edits and we only sample 10% of your edits. We can decide what reputation amount corresponds to X, X2, and X3. Now for the bumping thing, perhaps we tweak it so that the system only bumps questions if the asker is the one that edited the question.

Comment: @Ike As I understand it, it's already a violation of the community standards to do that. You mentioned one place our help center links to that encourages "thanks", but [another place we linked to](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (by Jon Skeet himself) discourages it.

Comment: @mason For sure, but just pointing out it's a little teeny bit murky. A simply line in that main section (not in the links) saying, "Don't put `Hi` and `Thanks` sort of things" would clear the right up. But what caught my attention here is that we want to call what this user is doing a *"trivial edit"*. To me it's not trivial -- it's not like a questionable formatting change. If we are definitely set on the idea that "hi" and "thanks" kind of comments do not belong in a question, then what this user is doing might even be commendable, even if he was doing it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: I believe we are as definitely set as we can be, as the community consensus seems clear. I absolutely think what the user is doing is commendable, but perhaps he should wait until he can make edits on his own for such a small change.

Comment: *perhaps we tweak it so that the system only bumps questions if the asker is the one that edited the question* @mason - No, other people's edits improve questions too. If another user's edit turns an unclear question into a good, clear, answerable one then that question should get bumped.

Comment: @BSMP I don't know that I've seen the case where a 3rd party edit has significantly changed a question from unanswerable to answerable. It might make it clearer, but I don't want questions to be bumped just because they're clearer.

Comment: *I don't want questions to be bumped just because they're clearer.* @mason - I'm pretty sure the system does though.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, I'm aware. I'm saying it should not do that.