# How should I act with continuous and intrusive changer?

Tags: discussion

I created a question: [Why this Go recursion code is so Slow? (Also requires almost 10 times more memory than Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122281/why-this-go-recursion-code-is-so-slow-also-requires-almost-10-times-more-memor)

Usually I mark names of languages as code `Ruby`, `Go`, `JS`, `PHP`, `Python`. I do it for years in sake of respect to programming. And this style does not bothers anybody.

This time user @Flimzy appears, he started to argue with me, did not giving any notes about programming and this task itself. But just change  the way languages names decorated, because it hard to read for him.

Editing is very helpful feature, when it used correctly. Some times users fix grammar mistakes in English and it's really makes sense. Big thanks for their work. But not in this case of applying useless changes.

when @Flimzy start to walk all over my posts and change decorations in them, throw away updates and so on, I flag his comment in the post about `Go`, explain situation, and this post become frozen, I cannot now share the correct solution about boundary checking and write barrier checking.

The question is: Are there some way to prevent such kind of editors?

And how should I act in this situation. I do not want to start a editions war with him and role back every change this guy makes, but also I do not want to have such intrusive person who editing my 2 years old questions without really needs.

Comment: I'll unlock the question now, but please do not further edit language names as inline code blocks as mentioned in BSMP's answer below.

Comment: Any "why does foo suck so bad" question that needs to be tagged with [foo] requires a very delicate touch.  Best to avoid any comparison, just state the foo problem you observed along with notes on how you measured and what you expected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Usually I mark names of languages as code Ruby, Go, PHP, Python.

You actually aren't supposed to do that. See: [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

So in this case the edits are actually correct. That said, I don't think there's a strong consensus on serial edits: [Serial editing in general: acceptable or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258424/serial-editing-in-general-acceptable-or-not) Some people think it's fine as long as the edits are good and other think getting a bunch of your posts edited at the same time, especially for something minor, is irritating.

> And how should I act in this situation.

You already did the right thing: flag a post/comment for moderator attention and explain the situation. This might mean the post gets locked like yours did but that's a temporary to prevent edit wars. You'll be able to post an answer after it's unlocked.

Answer (score 18):

> ... and this post become frozen, ...

I assume thats a temporary countermeasure to stop your edit war. Don't worry, just resolve that conflict, e.g. by discussing it on Meta (as you did) then the Moderators will be glad to remove the lock.

> Are there some way to prevent such kind of editors?

If the edits were *harmful*, yes, then that could be prevented. But in this case, the edits are *in-line with formatting best practices here on SO*. The user tried to improve your questions with good intentions.

> ... useless changes ...

I'd rather say *minor*, not *useless*. If all posts an SO are formatted the same way, they are easier to read and understand, and they are easier to automatically process (e.g. for search or code syntax highlighting).

I'm still surprised that you spend that much time on *two backticks* though. Is it really that relevant?¹

---

<sub>¹ For sure that also applies to redoing the edit without the posters approval. Remember: SO is a *collaborative effort*</sub>